# Overlapping fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an android app using fragment---

My layout for portrait mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topics"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        >               
        <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/cat_list_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.gitanjal.together.view.CategoryListFragment"
        />              
    </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Layout for landscape mode:--

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:weightSum="5"
>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/cat_list_home"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    class="com.gitanjal.together.view.CategoryListFragment" >

</fragment>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/topics"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    >

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my app works as follows:-

In portrait mode after login, a category grid is displayed;there is a button "Create Category" , which on click loads a fragment "FormSuggestCategoryFragment" to display a form where user can enter name and description of a new category as a suggestion to the admin to create this category.

In landscape mode after login, there is a fragment displaying the category list on the left , on clicking the "create category" button the form for suggesting category gets displayed by a fragment on the right .

Now the problem I am facing is as follows:-

In landscape mode after loading the form on right if I rotate the device the two fragments (one displaying the categories and other displaying the form) gets overlapped.

The method showSuggestCategoryForm:

```
private void showSuggestCategoryForm()
{

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {           

        FormSuggestCategoryFragment formSuggestCategory=new FormSuggestCategoryFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.topics, formSuggestCategory,"suggestForm");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------In single pane mode : going to display create category form");
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),FormSuggestCategoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

The onCreate :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    newRequest.requestGetCategories(contextParent,this);                                //Make the request
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_grids, null, false);      
}
```

the onActivityCreated method:

```
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the create category button
            Button btnCreateCategory=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnCreateCategory);
            btnCreateCategory.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                //On clicking the Create category button display the fragment containing the Category create form : FormCreateCategoryFragment  
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AppSettings.print_string("isAdmin----------"+SessionManager.isAdmin());
                    if(SessionManager.isAdmin())
                    {
                        //If the user is an Admin ; show the form to create a new category
                        AppSettings.print_string("As an admin displaying createCategoryForm");
                        showCreateCategoryForm();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If the user is not an admin ; ask his suggestion for a new category
                        AppSettings.print_string("As not an admin displaying suggestCategoryForm");
                        showSuggestCategoryForm();


                    }



                }

            });


}
```

Comment: the landscape layout's **FrameLayout** you've given the layout_width as px instead of dp. just check this out. but i'm not sure

Comment: I have tried , i does not work

Comment: Could you please post the code of onCreate and onResume methods of the Activity from where you are making Fragment Transactions?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19317615/1237297). The point is to not do fragment transaction in case savedInstanceState is not null.

Comment: @singh.jagmohan , thank you for the link , i am trying it...

Comment: @singh.jagmohan , the link helped , though it might not the case with savedInstanceState not being null . it seemed to be a resource related issue .

Comment: Glad to be of service.